# Taking double numbers back to previous activity

Tags: android, double

This is what i want to do with my application:
Open overview screen, go to calculator by button.
Than multiply two numbers.
By clicking calculate the intent will finish.
Outcome of multiply will be shown in first (main) activity.

I do not know how to do the last bit, someone any idea?

Code first (main) activity, OverviewpageActivity.java

```
 package com.tip.calc;

 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.widget.Button;
 import android.widget.TextView;


 public class OverviewpageActivity extends Activity {
private TextView multiplydisplay2;
private Button btntocalculator;
private double multiply     = 0;


/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.overview);

    multiplydisplay2    = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.multiplydisplay2);
    btntocalculator = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btntocalculator);

    btntocalculator.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() { 
        public void onClick (View v)    { 
            Intent intent = new Intent(OverviewpageActivity.this, 
   TipcalcActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
  }
```

Code calculator acticvity, TipcalcActivity.java:

```
 package com.tip.calc;

 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.widget.Button;
 import android.widget.EditText;
 import android.widget.TextView;


 public class TipcalcActivity extends Activity  {
private EditText number1;
private EditText number2;
private TextView multiplydisplay;
private Button btncalculate;
private Button btnreset;
private double number1calc = 0;
private double number2calc = 0;
private double multiply     = 0;


/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    initControls();
}

private void initControls() {
    number1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.number1);
    number2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.number2);
    multiplydisplay = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.multiplydisplay);
    btncalculate = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btncalculate);
    btnreset = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnreset);
    btncalculate.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() { public void
 onClick (View v){ calculate(); }});
    btnreset.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() { public void 
 onClick (View v){ reset(); }});
}

private void calculate()    {
    // check if zero
    if(number1.getText().toString().trim().length() < 1 ){number1calc=0;}
    else{number1calc=Double.parseDouble(number1.getText().toString());}

    if(number2.getText().toString().trim().length() < 1 ){number2calc=0;}
    else{number2calc=Double.parseDouble(number2.getText().toString());}

//calculate
    multiply=(number1calc*number2calc);
    multiplydisplay.setText(Double.toString(multiply));
    finish();
}

private void reset()    {
    multiplydisplay.setText("");
    number1.setText("");
    number2.setText("");
    finish();
}
 }
```

Layout file, overview.xml:

```
 <LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >



<!-- multiply -->   
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_marginTop="20dp"  >
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="multiply:" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/multiplydisplay2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp" />
</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btntocalculator"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="To the calculator" />

 </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [startActivityforResult](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29) instead of startActivity in OverviewpageActivity.java and also override OnactivityResult in OverviewpageActivity.java.

Then in second activity you can set the result using [setResult](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setResult%28int,%20android.content.Intent%29). Pass the intent in setresult which will have the double value.
In [OnactivityResult](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onActivityResult%28int,%20int,%20android.content.Intent%29) you can get the intent from which you can extract double

Comment: http://remwebdevelopment.com/dev/a33/Passing-Bundles-Around-Activities.html . here is the sample code